# hamburger menu position of span's in animate

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to make hamburger menu icon and my problem is I want animate middle span to right side, I don't know how to do it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 10%;
}

span {
    display: block;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0;
  width: 40px;
}

.container:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: animation 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes animation {
  to { width: 20px; }
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/msds3c4j/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/msds3c4j/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
@keyframes animation {
  to { 
    width: 20px; 
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/myjta15L/)